# Laravel - can I bind an event to a notification?

Tags: laravel, events, notifications

First, I'll describe the context.
I have a lot of notifications that refering to changes in the `Offer`, `for example: offerEditedBySeller, offerEditedByAdmin, offerTurnOff, etc`. They are triggered in many places in controllers.
Now I'm implementing an expanded cache and I want to make the event `OfferChange` in which the cache for specific offer will be reloaded. First, I wanted to trigger these notifications in events, but I realized that to make it work, I'll have to duplicate every notification.
For example, let's assume I have the **event( new OfferEdited() )**. Its listeners will be **RefreshCacheForOffer, SendNotificationsAboutOfferEdit** etc. For every notification like `offerEdited` I need to create listener `SendNotificationsAboutOfferEdit`, which just trigger specific Notification. I think it's not what I want to reach.
Is there a way to bind events/listeners with a notification? No matter if it would be `offerEdited`, `offerApproved` or `offerDisapproved` it would be bind with the event `OfferChange`, which would trigger the listener `RefreshCacheForOffer` and the specific job next. This way I wouldn't have to change the code in every controller's action and create a lot of unnecessary events and listeners. Is it possible?
**Edit:**
I know I can just do:

```
$user->notify(new offerEdited($offer));
event( new OfferChange($offer) );
```

But I hope there is a way to better organize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid changing lots of code in your controllers you could model it inside your Model and pick up on the 'created' or 'updated' events of the model, and then call subsequent events.

```
class Offer extends Model
{

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::updated(function ($user) {
            // check for condition and trigger event such as OfferEditedBySeller
        });
    }
}
```

If you want to use event/listener architecture then I think one event and listener for ever notification is the way you have to go.

Alternatively, don't bother with events/listeners - just send your notifications from the controller or from the 'created' or 'updated' events of the model. Cut out the middleman (events/listeners) and you'll have more explicit code which is easier to follow.

Events/listeners are good when you need to decouple and abstract - but if you are doing explicit things then not using them might be simpler for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about model events. Let me try this in practice, if this solution will suit to my project, I'll accept your answer.